# click href with jqlite for jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm starting with unit testing in angular and angular in general.  I have an href that looks like:

```
<a class="my-awesome-class" name="remove-btn" ng-click="delete">×</a>
```

then in my unit test,

```
var element = angular.element("<my-directive></my-directive>");
compile(element)(scope);
var removeButton = element.find(".my-awesome-class")[0];
console.log(removeButton);
removeButton.click();
//expect(...);
```

So I can grab the removeButton.  But click() does not work.  Is there a way to click my href with jqlite for a jasmine unit test?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
removeButton.trigger('click');
```

Comment: I get "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Most likely that `removeButton` hasn't been set properly before. Modify your code accordingly. (What the hell, SO is not a microworking platform...!)

Comment: Isn't the jqLite method `triggerHandler()`? [angular.element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)